# Model file for Node/Express apps

Tags: node.js, express, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a Node/Express app with a Azure Cosmos DB backend. Currently my code to make the database calls live in the app.js file, and the database file in the app only refreshes when the app is restarted. I think I need to move my database code to a Model so that I can call the functions to interact with the database more easily. Is this the right approach? If so any tips on how to move the code are appreciated.

Here is the code currently in my app.js file for the cosmos db:

```js
//Create New CosmosClient
const endpoint = config.endpoint;
const key = config.key;

const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });

const HttpStatusCodes = { NOTFOUND: 404 };

const databaseId = config.database.id;
const containerId = config.container.id;
const partitionKey = { kind: "Hash", paths: ["/state"] };


/**
* Create the database if it does not exist
*/
async function createDatabase() {
  const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
  console.log(`Created database:\n${database.id}\n`);
}

/**
* Read the database definition
*/
async function readDatabase() {
  // const { body: databaseDefinition } = await client.database(databaseId).read();
  console.log(`Reading database:\n${databaseDefinition.id}\n`);
}

/**
* Create the container if it does not exist
*/

async function createContainer() {

 const { container } = await client.database(databaseId).containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId, partitionKey }, { offerThroughput: 400 });
 console.log(`Created container:\n${config.container.id}\n`);
}

/**
 * Read the container definition
*/
async function readContainer() {
   const { resource: containerDefinition } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).read();
 console.log(`Reading container:\n${containerDefinition.id}\n`);
}

/**
* Exit the app with a prompt
* @param {message} message - The message to display
*/
function exit(message) {
  console.log(message);
  console.log('Press any key to exit');
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.on('data', process.exit.bind(process, 0));
}

var newdb = createDatabase()
  // .then(() => readDatabase())
  .then(() => createContainer())
  .then(() => readContainer())
  .then(() => queryContainer())
  .then(() => { exit(`Completed successfully`); })
  .catch((error) => { exit(`Completed with error ${JSON.stringify(error)}`) });

  /**
* Query the container using SQL
 */
async function queryContainer() {
  console.log(`Querying container:\n${config.container.id}`);

  // query to return all completed items
  const querySpec = {
     query: "SELECT r.id, r.Temp, r.DateTime, r.Sensor, r.Device FROM root r",
     parameters: [
         {
          name: "@completed",
          value: false
         }
     ]
 };
 const { resources } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec, {enableCrossPartitionQuery:true}).fetchAll();

 for (var queryResult of resources) {
     let dataString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
     // console.log(`\tQuery returned ${dataString}\n`)
     var ojb = JSON.parse(dataString)
     resultString.push(ojb)
     // console.log(resultString)
 }
 app.locals.resultString = resultString; 
};
```

c

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your app generally this way.

```
src
│   app.js          # App entry point
└───api             # Express route controllers for all the endpoints of the app
└───config          # Environment variables and configuration related stuff
└───models          # Database models
└───routes          # All the routes
└───controllers     # All the functions holds the business logic
```

Checkout code of this app:
https://github.com/pprathameshmore/QuoteGarden

Comment: So maybe I need a controller file as well as a model file? Then maybe call the functions in the controller file from the route file? Is that what you suggest?

Comment: Yes, refactor your code that will easy to maintain code.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you then accept it and upvote. Thanks!